# "or" between items

Tags: grammar, commas, formal-language, formality, academic-writing

Which option is the proper in academic writing for "or" items (apples/pears/oranges):

> 1. I am going to eat red apples **or** yellow pears **or** green oranges.

> 2. I am going to eat red apples, **or** yellow pears, **or** green oranges.

> 3. I am going to eat red apples, yellow pears **or** green oranges.

> 4. I am going to eat red apples, yellow pears, **or** green oranges.

Comment: Academic or not, there is no need for _or_ between the first two items in the list. I wouldn't use a comma before _or_.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks! But maybe in #4 one may think if we do not add "or" that apples and pears are one group: "I am going to eat red apples and yellow pears, or green oranges." ?

Comment: No-one would think that unless you added _and_.

Answer (score 2):

The standard phrasing is #4. "Or" needs to be used before the last item only.

The additional ("Oxford") comma is not necessary; many style guides rule against it. In this case, I think it helps avoid ambiguity.

Comment: But in #4 one may think if we do not add or that apples and pears are one group: "I am going to eat red apples and yellow pears, or green oranges."